# Need examples of invertible operators on real finite-dimensional vector space without squareroots

Tags: linear-algebra

As per the title, having trouble googling for such examples, I know from my textbook that the operator of multiplication by $-1$ on $R^n$ Has no squares roots, just wanted more examples to have an intuition or see if theres any sort of pattern of invertible operators on real finite-dimensional vectors spaces without square roots.

Comment: A couple things to first clarify, what level is the context of this question? Are you asking for general $n\times n$ matrices at an introductory level? Are you asking about specific cases of functional analysis, where, in fact you can have real finite dimensional vector spaces? You say invertible, so this can only be the case of a square matrix. However, are you specifying a linear map, a field, and bases for the vector spaces?

Comment: Introductory level. A general n by n matrix would work. Yes, I'm looking for specific cases or examples as per title. Yes, I believe that all operators on finite dimensional vector spaces have square matrixes, invertible or not. Any linear map that is invertible and has no square roots and is an operator on a finite dimensional vector space would do, as long as the finite dimensional vector space is on the field of real numbers.